# Does python support to import package

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7, and have following code strucure

```
model
    __init__.py
    order.py
cart.py
```

That is, I define a package named `model`, and in this package, I define a module `order`, and I define a class in order.py

```
class MyOrder(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getname(self):
        return self.name
```

In the cart.py, the code is:

```
import model

x = model.order.MyOrder("Book")
print x.getname()
```

When I run it, it complains that `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'order'`,

But the following is correct:

```
import model.order

x = model.order.MyOrder("Book")
print x.getname()
```

It looks that I can't import package (like `import model`) ?

Comment: Try `from model import order`

Comment: Importing a package doesn't auto-load its submodules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have `model` automatically import `order` so it's available, you should do that in `__init__.py`. Simply put the following inside `model/__init__.py`:

```
from . import order
```

After that, you should be able to access `model.order` with just `import model`.